# GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES and glReadPixels

Tags: ios, glsl, fragment-shader

When I am using the GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES texture; the fragment shader seems to be writing to it fine and I can observe it has the right values when I use gpuTrace in xCode.  But when I read it back using

```
glReadPixels( 0, 0, self.imageSize->v[0], self.imageSize->v[1], GL_RGBA, type, pixels );
```

The pixels components are either floating -0 or floating 1.  Is this because the float values are getting unexpectedly clipped?  Is there a way to read back the float values as they were originally written?  If I use `GL_RGBA16F_EXT` or `GL_RGBA32F_EXT` instead of `GL_RGBA` I get invalid enum.

Based on feedback from Rabbid76

```
int formatExt, typeExt;
glGetIntegerv( GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, &formatExt );
glGetIntegerv( GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE, &typeExt );

[ self traceLog:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"Implementation format is %@, type is %@", [ TextureImage strForFormat:formatExt ], [ TextureImage strForType:typeExt ] ] ];
```

The values returned are "Implementation format is GL_RGBA, type is GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES".  Which probably implies that HALF_FLOAT is the only value that it is able to read back.  I am still investigating if it would be possible for it to read back GL_FLOAT, because despite what glGetIntegerv returns glReadPixels does not flag GL_FLOAT with invalid Enum; it accepts and processes it, but the floats are not something that appear to be the right floats; so it appears to be doing some unexpected conversions.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [`glReadPixels` (OpenGL ES 3.1)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) which says:

> `void glReadPixels(
>       GLint   x,
>       GLint   y,
>       GLsizei width,
>       GLsizei height,
>       GLenum  format,
>       GLenum  type,
>       GLvoid * data);`
>   
>   `format`
>   Specifies the format of the pixel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: `GL_RGBA`, and `GL_RGBA_INTEGER`. An implementation-chosen format will also be accepted. This can be queried with [`glGet`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/glGet.xhtml) and `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT`.
>   
>   `type`
>   Specifies the data type of the pixel data. Must be one of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV`, `GL_INT`, or `GL_FLOAT`. An implementation-chosen type will also be accepted. This can be queried with [`glGet`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/glGet.xhtml) and `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE`.

This means you have to read the implementation-chosen `format` and `type`, to read back the float values as they were originally written:

```
int format = glGet(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT);
int type   = glGet(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE);
glReadPixels( 
    0, 0, self.imageSize->v[0], self.imageSize->v[1],
    format, type, pixels );
```

See the documentation of [`glGet` (OpenGL ES 3.1)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/glGet.xhtml):

> `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT`
>   params returns one value, the format chosen by the implementation in which pixels may be read from the color buffer **of the currently bound framebuffer**.
>   
>   `GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE`
>   params returns one value, the type chosen by the implementation with which pixels may be read from the color buffer **of the currently bound framebuffer**.